# String.ToCharArray() stored in StringCollection conversion to numbers and back in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, string, stringcollection

I have a string which was converted to a char array and stored in a stringcollection, how do I return the numerical value for the character in each string? How can I reverse this process, getting the character from the numerical value?

I know I could code a `Select Case` statement, but that would take a very long time as I need to cover every character a person could want to conceivably use in the English language, including punctuation.

Is there already a method built into vb.net for doing this?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Convert` class has methods that can convert between characters and integers:

```
Dim c As Char = "A"C
Dim i As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(c)
Dim c2 As Char = Convert.ToChar(i)
```

To loop the values converted from the characters in a string into an array of integers:

```
Dim codes(theString.Length - 1) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 to theString.Length - 1
    codes(i) = Convert.ToInt32(theString.Chars(i))
Next
```

Comment: @Cyclone: That is a character literal. "A" is a string literal containing one character, and "A"C is a character literal.

Comment: Okay, so I need to have the character literal if I want this to work? Could I convert a whole string at once?

Comment: If you want to get the character for each character in a string, you will have to loop the string and convert each character. There is no built in method to convert a string to an array of integers.

Comment: Err, okay, if each character is not specifically mentioned as a string, like your first line, how do I declare it as a char literal? Meaning, I have a variable which is holding the value.

Comment: Since I didnt have it as a literal, here is my code: For Each letter As Char In Text
                Output = (Convert.ToInt32(letter))

            Next

Comment: That failed, I printed out the result and it epicly failed.

Comment: As you are storing all the values in the same variable they will overwrite each other, so you only get the code of the last character. Declare an array with the same length as the string, and put the result from converting each character in an element in the array.

Comment: How do I add each character to an array? I have only used StringCollection and ArrayList before.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
For Each c As Char In yourString
    Dim i As Int32 = DirectCast(c, Int32)
Next
```

Remeber that `System.String` implements `IEnumerable<Char>` so it is legal to `For Each` over it.  And converting between a character and a number is as simple as casting between `System.Char` and `System.Int32` (here I have shown how to get the numeric value for each character in the string).

Comment: So I is my returned integer for that single character?

Comment: It did not work, I got"'Char' values cannot be converted to 'Integer'. Use 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.AscW' to interpret a character as a Unicode value or 'Microsoft.VisualBasic.Val' to interpret it as a digit."

Comment: Hmm... VB.NET apparently doesn't allow this - C# allows you to cast from `Char` to `Int32`.  You will need to use the `Convert` methods that Guffa mentions to do the conversions.